# Mysql/Maridb Update is not working

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Suppose a table contains data like

```
MariaDB [c]> select * from t2;
+-----+
| abc |
+-----+
|   1 |
|   3 |
|   5 |
+-----+
```

Suppose my update command is

```
MariaDB [c]> update t2 set abc = abc+2;
```

It give following error

```
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '3' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

While the above command works fine in oracle 10g, Is it some kind of bug or what?

Comment: This is because you may have primary key constraint on the column.Column should have unique values after updating.

Comment: But after full update column will have unique value,But why this works in oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is just an illustration and trivial.

```
create table t2
(   id int auto_increment primary key,
    abc int not null,
    unique key(abc)
);
insert t2(abc) values (1),(3),(5); -- 3 rows added

update t2 set abc = abc+2; -- Error Code 1062: Duplicate entry '3' for key 'abc'
```

The above error occurred because the update marched in the order of the primary key, also the physical ordering, and changing the 1 to a 3 violated the 3 that was already in place via the `unique key`. The fact that the end state would make every thing OK, ideally, doesn't keep it from failing at that moment.

To illustrate this working in this highly rigged example knowing there is no other data:

```
truncate table t2; -- the data wasn't modified but for the paranoid, clear and re-insert
insert t2(abc) values (1),(3),(5); -- 3 rows added
```

Try it bottom up (so that the Unique constraint is not violated):

```
update t2 set abc = abc+2 order by abc desc;
select * from t2;
+----+-----+
| id | abc |
+----+-----+
|  1 |   3 |
|  2 |   5 |
|  3 |   7 |
+----+-----+
```

It leverages the ability to have an `order by` in an update statement.

So it comes down to knowing your data and what you can get away with. Saying it worked on Oracle as you did in comments is on another db platform and with some other schema. So that is mute.

Comment: Thanks man , Actually I issued a bug at jira.mariadb.com ,and hopefully this will be resolved.

Comment: I don't see it as a bug. Just saying.